# Trigger WPF doubleanimation from Powershell codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

This is Powershell/WPF (The loaded assemblies are pasted from my project and mostly not needed for this)

I am making an animated flyout button, it works as intended, I click the button, it slides into position, at the end of the animation it hides and a different button appears in its place with the opposite animation ready waiting to be clicked, this behavior toggles fine. I would like to make clicking anywhere (not solely the second button) trigger moving the second button back.

In the real script a popup window appears, and my intent is to make it dismissible by clicking anywhere outside the window in addition to the button itself. I currently have this working but if the button isnt directly clicked the close animation gets skipped because I cant(don't know how to) trigger it without the button.

I know it's highly likely someone knows how to do this in C#, and I am willing to take examples and figure out how to make a comparable PS codebehind, so I tagged C# too, but if there is a PS method someone knows, that would be extremely helpful.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration, presentationCore
[xml]$xaml='
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" Width="500" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoMouseOverButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="MovableButton1" Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#EEEEEE" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="70" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">Button1<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Name="ButtonAnimation1" From="70" To="207" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard></EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="MovableButton2" Canvas.Left="207" Canvas.Top="0" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#EEEEEE" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="70" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">Button2<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Name="ButtonAnimation2" From="207" To="70" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard></EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>'
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$Button1=$Window.FindName("MovableButton1")
$Button2=$Window.FindName("MovableButton2")
$ButtonAnimation1=$Window.FindName("ButtonAnimation1")
$ButtonAnimation2=$Window.FindName("ButtonAnimation2")
$Button1.Add_Click({
    write-host FirstButtonClicked
})
$Button2.Add_Click({
    write-host SecondButtonClicked
})
$ButtonAnimation1.Add_Completed({
    write-host AnimationCompleted
    $Button1.Visibility="Hidden"
    $Button2.Visibility="Visible"
})
$ButtonAnimation2.Add_Completed({
    write-host AnimationCompleted
    $Button1.Visibility="Visible"
    $Button2.Visibility="Hidden"
})
$window.Show()
$appContext=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```

The full project for reference: https://github.com/illsk1lls/PowerPlayer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to a data trigger and using a hidden textbox to store a value, the animations trigger if the value is switched. Now any button (or anything else that can change the value) can trigger the animation(s)

One drawback is we do lose the ability to listen for a "Completed" event for an animation attached to a data trigger, as they only pop from user input, e.g. a click

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration, presentationCore
[xml]$xaml='
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MovingButtonSample" Height="150" Width="270">
            <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoMouseOverButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock Visibility="Hidden" Name="ButtonData"/>
        <Button Name="Button1" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#DDDDDD" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="25" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">>><Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButtonData, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="5" To="180" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style></Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="Button2" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="0" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#DDDDDD" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="25" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">Playlist<Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButtonData, Path=Text}" Value="0">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="295" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style></Button.Style>
        </Button>
    <Button Name="Button3" Canvas.Top="50" Height="20" Width="40"/>
</Canvas>
</Window>'
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$global:Pressed=0
$Button1=$Window.FindName("Button1")
$Button2=$Window.FindName("Button2")
$Button3=$Window.FindName("Button3")
$ButtonData=$Window.FindName("ButtonData")
function toggleFlyout(){
    Switch($Pressed){
    0{
        $ButtonData.Text='1'
        $Button1.Height="18"
        $Button1.Width="70"
        $global:Pressed=1
        $Button1.Visibility="visible"
        $Button2.Visibility="hidden"
        $Button2.Content=">>"
        $Button1.Content="Hello"
    }
    1{
        $ButtonData.Text='0'
        $Button1.Height="18"
        $Button1.Width="25"
        $Button1.Visibility="hidden"
        $Button2.Visibility="visible"
        $global:Pressed=0
    }
    }   
}
$Button1.Add_Click({
toggleFlyout    
})
$Button2.Add_Click({
toggleFlyout    
})
$Button3.Add_Click({
toggleFlyout    
})
$window.Show()
$appContext=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```